# How to get data values of a bootstrap modal using jQuery or javascript on clicking button inside the modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to get data values of a bootstrap modal on clicking button inside the modal.
Here is my modal -

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cancel</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body"> 
                                    Are you sure you want to cancel this?
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" id="savebutton" class="btn btn-success" >Yes</button>  
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
```

And here is the way I am passing the data to modal -

**Update -**

```
    <button data-target='#myModal' id='link' data-toggle='modal' data-id="1"  class='btn btn-danger cancel_modal' style='font-size:10px;padding:2px 5px;color:white;' >Cancel 1</button>
    <button data-target='#myModal' id='link' data-toggle='modal' data-id="2"  class='btn btn-danger cancel_modal' style='font-size:10px;padding:2px 5px;color:white;' >Cancel 2</button>
    <button data-target='#myModal' id='link' data-toggle='modal' data-id="3"  class='btn btn-danger cancel_modal' style='font-size:10px;padding:2px 5px;color:white;' >Cancel 3</button>
    ...
    ..
    .
    <button data-target='#myModal' id='link' data-toggle='modal' data-id="n"  class='btn btn-danger cancel_modal' style='font-size:10px;padding:2px 5px;color:white;' >Cancel n</button>
```

*Modal can be called from any one of the many buttons and I need to get the data-id of the concerned button only. e.g.- if I click on "Cancel 1" button, I should get data-id as 1 after clicking "Yes" button in modal.*

I want to get the modal data value of "id" field which is 1234 on clicking "Yes" button in this modal using jQuery or javascript.

Comment: var id=document.getElementById('savebutton').getAttribute("data-id");

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried but it is returning null instead of the value. Here is the jsfiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/4771/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have modifed your fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/exr00e0d/

you had taken href. instead of that i took the target(modal).

```
$('.cancel_modal').click(function() {
   //alert('called');
    // we want to copy the 'id' from the button to the modal
    var href = $(this).data('target');
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    // since the value of href is what we want, so I just did it like so
    alert(href);
    // used it as the selector for the modal
    alert(id);
    $(href).data('id', id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function getid() {
var id=document.getElementById('savebutton').getAttribute("data-‌​id");
return id;
}

<button type="button" id="savebutton" class="btn btn-success" onclick="getid()" >Yes</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried but it is returning null instead of the value. Here is the jsfiddle-  http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/4771/

Comment: @gauravparmar you missed data-* ie data attribute ,  data-id="1234"

Comment: @gauravparmar I updated fiddle check now... http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/4777/

Comment: Actually I have multiple dynamically generated "Cancel" buttons to open the modal and I want to get the data-id of the concerned button on clicking "Yes" inside the modal. Here is the updated jsfiddle if you could please help - http://jsfiddle.net/gauravparmar/Au9tc/4812/

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery

```
$('#savebutton').click(function() {
    var id = $('#link').data('id');
    // if for some reason, the code above doesn't work,
    // $('#link').attr('data-id');
    console.log(id);
});
```

Edit:

Looking at [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/4776/)

```
$('#link').click(function() {
    // we want to copy the 'id' from the button to the modal
    var target = $(this).attr('target');
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    $(target).data('id', id);
});

$('#savebutton').click(function() {
    // now we grab it from the modal
    var id = $('#addBookDialog').data('id');

    console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not working. Please tell what am I doing wrong? Here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/4776/

Comment: i just looked at into your jsfiddle again, i realised that on your "load type" jsfiddle option should be "onLoad"... even with my old code it should work.

Comment: Sorry. I am not well-versed with Bootstrap modals. I tried using above solution but it is not working for me when I have multiple modal opening links with same id which is my case. May be I did something wrong. Can you please check this updated jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gauravparmar/Au9tc/4792/

Comment: you can't have multiple element with the same Id in your fiddle. In the javascript dropdown option, I've changed the load type to "onLoad" so my script would run. Here's the new fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/4793/

Comment: Actually I have multiple dynamically generated "Cancel" buttons to open the modal and I want to get the data-id of the concerned button on clicking "Yes" inside the modal. Here is the updated jsfiddle if you could please help - http://jsfiddle.net/gauravparmar/Au9tc/4812/

Comment: I've updated your fiddle, the same solution, I just changed the property to properly get the targeted modal from the "cancel" button. http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/4814/